# ASP.NET Core jquery Autocomplete returns blank lines in the list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, autocomplete

I am using ASP.NET Core jquery Autocomplete with Boostrap 4 
I have successfully run the following example from : https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

I am now looking to use data from my controller which returns data properly. 
The result that I get is blank lines.

[image]

Here is my Razor page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label>Autocomplete Example: </label>
    <input id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" />
</div>
<script>
    $("#LastName").autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("GetName","Home")'
    });
</script>
```

Here's my controller
            [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetName(string term)
        {

```
        List<TransactionName> list = new List<TransactionName>()
        {

            new TransactionName {Id=1,LastName="Linda" },
            new TransactionName {Id=2,LastName="Donna" },
            new TransactionName {Id=3,LastName="Maryanne" },
            new TransactionName {Id=4,LastName="Deb" },
            new TransactionName {Id=5,LastName="Liz" },
            new TransactionName {Id=6,LastName="Bobby" },
            new TransactionName {Id=7,LastName="Beth" }

    };
        var result = (from N in list
                        where N.LastName.Contains(term)
                        select new {N.LastName });
        return Json(result);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed the following based on the jquery Autocomplete documentation:

```
    var result = (from N in list
                    where N.LastName.Contains(term)
                    select new {value=N.LastName });
```

Here's a portion of the documentation taken from their site.
Multiple types supported:
Array: An array can be used for local data. There are two supported formats:
An array of strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

Comment: Baiting with bounties is rude if you're simply going to accept your own answer.